# What is the best way to add a new value to an existing array in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save an varying number of values (of the same type) for each user in a firestore document. This is being done using an array.

When the user decides to add a new value I have a function for each of the three operations that need to be done.

- Get the current array from the database and assign it to a variable
- Add the user input  to the array using push()
- Replace the old array in the database

```
//gets arr from database
  function get() {
    console.log(arr);
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("test")
      .doc("testArray")
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        setArr(doc.data().arr);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(arr);
        console.log("value retrieved");
      });
  }

  //adds new object to arr
  function add() {
    arr.push({
      a: 89,
      b: 34,
    });
    console.log("value added");
    console.log(arr);
  }

  //adds arr to database
  function updateArray() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("test")
      .doc("testArray")
      .set({
        arr: arr,
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("array updated");
      });
  }
```

**My goal is to run all of these operations using one function so it can be done with one button press.**

I am not very familiar with asynchronous js but I have managed to get the first two functions running in order using async/await.

```
 //gets arr from database
  async function get() {
    console.log(arr);
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("test")
      .doc("testArray")
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        setArr(doc.data().arr);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(arr);
        console.log("value retrieved");
      });

    add();
  }

async function call() {
    await get();
    updateArray();
  }
```

However the third function still seems to run first, causing the data in the database to be replaced with an empty array before the new data is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update an array in firestore use arrayUnion

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");    
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});
```

To remove an array in firestore use arrayRemove

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");
washingtonRef.update({
    regions: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove("east_coast")
});
```

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
const db = firebase
.firestore()
.collection("test")
.doc("testArray");

function updateArr() {
db.update({
  arr: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
    {
      a: 2,
      b: 34,
    }
  ),
});
```

}

> For arrays inside maps it only replaces the current value. Regardless
> of if the array element has the same value

[database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkGbm.jpg)